# Removal of sun.misc.Unsafe in Java 9 will break Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, java-9, unsafe

I read [here](http://blog.dripstat.com/removal-of-sun-misc-unsafe-a-disaster-in-the-making/) that Spring and many other popular libraries will break if Oracle removes `sun.misc.Unsafe` in Java 9. However, there are no static references to this class in Spring or Hibernate. So, is that claim true?

BTW there are 64 references to `Unsafe` in Java 8, but if Oracle removes that class they will update all of them and no library will be affected (unless they use `Unsafe` directly that is).

Comment: Unsafe will not be removed from the JDK, just be hidden. So the JDK can internally still access it. This is made possible by the Jigsaw module concept.

Comment: So what does that mean for the average Java developer compiling their Spring-Hibernate applications to war files using maven and dropping it into Tomcat / Jetty? Will my application start up or will it require fidgeting with the container to make it work?

Comment: @Lluis Martinez Is there a suitable answer to this already? If yes, could you mark one please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mark Reinhold had a talk during JVM Language Summit 2015 titled [*The Secret History and Tragic Fate of sun.misc.Unsafe*](https://youtu.be/4HG0YQVy8UM). Although these talks have plenty of disclaimers on them, you can see the proposed approach at [10:23](https://youtu.be/4HG0YQVy8UM?t=10m23s), which is described in [JEP260](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260).

The general idea is:

1. replace existing functionality with safer, supported APIs
2. deprecate the previously existing `Unsafe` APIs that has been replaced
3. remove the deprecated code in the next version

Here is some relevant text from JEP260 (taken from October 20th 2015):

> In JDK 9 we propose to:
>
> - Encapsulate all non-critical internal APIs by default: The modules that define them will not export their packages for outside use. (Access to such APIs will be available, as a last resort, via a command-line flag at both compile time and run time, unless those APIs are revised or removed for other reasons.)
> - Encapsulate critical internal APIs for which supported replacements exist in JDK 8, in the same manner and with the same last-resort workaround. (A supported replacement is one that is either part of the Java SE 8 standard (i.e., in a java.* or javax.* package) or else JDK-specific and annotated with @jdk.Exported (typically in a com.sun.* or jdk.* package).)
> - Not encapsulate critical internal APIs for which supported replacements do not exist in JDK 8 and, further, deprecate those which have supported replacements in JDK 9 with the intent to encapsulate them, or possibly even remove them, in JDK 10.
>
> ...
>
> **Critical internal APIs for which replacements are introduced in JDK 9 will be deprecated in JDK 9 and either encapsulated or removed in JDK 10.**

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/07/Feedback-For-Java-9-Feature-List) resource provides a proper understanding of the current status of JDK 9 and its features. The community started a discussion related to Unsafe and its future into the future of java. The given document is the effort of the community to react to [JEP-260](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) that proposes hiding some internal APIs but leaving accessible some critical APIs, among witch Unsafe. As extracted from the document itself:

> The critical internal APIs proposed to remain accessible in JDK 9 are:
>
> sun.misc.Cleaner
>
> sun.misc.{Signal,SignalHandler}
>
> sun.misc.Unsafe (The functionality of many of the methods in this
>   class is now available via variable handles (JEP 193).)
>
> sun.reflect.Reflection::getCallerClass (The functionality of this
>   method may be provided in a standard form via JEP 259.)
>
> sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory

So to conclude, at least based on the [given](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260) JEP, Unsafe should remain.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the references are not in the core of Spring or Hibernate, but somewhere else. The document linked says with regard to Spring

> Spring Framework (via Objenesis, with a fallback)

I tried to search for usages of Unsafe in the project I am currently working on, so there are still quite some libraries which may break.

result of quick search:

- Guava
- GWT
- Netty
- Jersey-Common
- Infinispan
- Jboss-Modules

Comment: You're right, Guava has a few references but I read they provide a fallback so it's not a hard dependence. https://github.com/google/guava/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sun.misc.unsafe

Comment: No references in Spring https://github.com/spring/spring/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sun.misc.unsafe

Comment: @LluisMartinez: Your link points to "Spring RTS game engine", "an Open Source Real Time Strategy game engine". This has nothing to do with the Spring the OP asked about.

Comment: @Nicolai Which link? I'm the OP by the way :-)

Comment: The link in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417320/removal-of-sun-misc-unsafe-in-java-9-will-break-spring-hibernate/31460037?noredirect=1#comment50931848_31460037).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the linked document. Spring does not have a direct dependency on `Unsafe`, but Spring depends on Objenesis and Objenesis depends on `Unsafe`.

Dependency for Objenesis on `Unsafe`: https://github.com/easymock/objenesis/blob/master/main/src/main/java/org/objenesis/instantiator/sun/UnsafeFactoryInstantiator.java

Spring's dependency on Objenesis is itself a bit strange. Spring's build script fetches the Objenesis binary and makes bytecode-level changes using the JarJar tool. You can see what it does in the following build script: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle (at time of writing, see lines 326-343, and 347).

This essentially means that Spring's "spring-core" binary ends up containing a load of classes under the org.springframework.objenesis.* package structure, but those classes were originally stored in source in Objenesis GitHub, published as a binary by the Objenesis team, fetched during Spring's build, repackaged to org.springframework.* packages and then republished as part of Spring. That's why you are having trouble finding them.

Spring uses `Unsafe` (via Objenesis) to create classes without first calling the constructor.